# Validate and Modify Time Input on the Fly

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript, how can I validate and modify the user time input using the regular expression and `string.replace` function so that instead of telling the user anything, it will validate and modify the input on the fly?

For example, the user input could be `1.12p` `13:12` `1,12PM`, but the final result should always be `1:12 PM`.

Does anyone have examples on how to do so?

PS. I know that using timepicker is a way more efficient way, but I have to use the user input in this case

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I do have some advice.  When searching out a method to do this and if you can support HTML5, use the [input DOM event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/input), and for the love of all things cute and fluffy, don't use keyup or keydown events.  they will cause you headache after headache.  This is all if you can support HTML5 though, unfortunately. :\

Comment: Unfortunately I am working with some really old source that does not even use jQuery, let alone HTML5.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple regex you could use as a starting point:

```
(\d{1,2})\s*[.,:;]\s*(\d{1,2})\s*(([Aa]|[Pp])[Mm]?)?
```

```
^        ^  ^     ^  ^        ^  ^ ^         ^
Hour group  |     |  Minutes  |  | |         M is optional
         |  Valid separators  |  | Case-insensitivity
         |        |           |  AM/PM group
         ------------------------------Allow spaces
```

You'd still need to validate that the time is valid (59:99 is probably not valid), but this would at least make it easier to parse the string in javascript. After you've parsed it, you can print it back out however you want.

*EDIT: Oops. Forgot that javascript does not support named groups. Just use numbered groups to the same effect.*

**EXAMPLE**
What the hay... here's a complete working example. When to validate (and what to do with invalid input) is left up to you:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
function parseTime( timeString ){
    var timePattern = /(\d{1,2})\s*[.,:;]\s*(\d{1,2})\s*(([Aa]|[Pp])[Mm]?)?/;
    var timeMatch = timePattern.exec( timeString );

    var INVALID = null;

    if ( timeMatch !== null ){
        var hour = timeMatch[1];
        var minute = timeMatch[2];
        var ampm = timeMatch[3];

        if ( minute < 0 || minute > 59 )
            return INVALID;

        if ( ampm != "" ){
            if ( hour < 1 || hour > 12 )
                return INVALID;

            ampm = ampm.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() == "A" ? "AM" : "PM";
        } else {
            if ( hour > 23 )
                return INVALID;

            ampm = ( hour < 13 ? "AM" : "PM" );
            hour = hour % 12;
            if ( hour == 0 ) hour = 12;
        }

        return hour + ":" + minute + " " + ampm;
    } else {
        return INVALID;
    }
}

function unitTest(){
    var testStrings = [
        ["1:30 PM", "1:30 PM"],
        ["1.30p", "1:30 PM"],
        ["1;30a", "1:30 AM"],
        ["59:99 PM", null],
        ["0,30", "12:30 AM"],
        ["15:00", "3:00 PM"],
        ["abc", null] ];

    var testResults;
    testResults = "<table><tr><th>Input</th><th>Expected</th><th>Actual</th></tr>";

    for (var i = 0; i < testStrings.length; i++){
        testResults +=
            "<tr>" +
                "<td>" + testStrings[i][0] + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + testStrings[i][1] + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + parseTime( testStrings[i][0] ) + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + ( testStrings[i][1] == parseTime( testStrings[i][0] ) ?
                            "<span style='color:green'>Success</span>" :
                            "<span style='color:red'>Failure</span>" ) +
                "</td>" +
            "</tr>";
    }

    testResults += "</table>";

    this.document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = testResults;
}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="unitTest();">

        <div id="results">
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

> Input Expected Actual
>   1:30 PM 1:30 PM 1:30 PM Success
>   1.30p 1:30 PM 1:30 PM Success
>   1;30a 1:30 AM 1:30 AM Success
>   59:99 PM null null Success
>   0,30 12:30 AM 12:30 AM Success
>   15:00 3:00 PM 3:00 PM Success
>   abc null null Success